# Anode rod location

Tags: water-heater, anode

I have an old (installed ‘06) Kenmore Power Miser 12 and I cannot figure out where the anode rod is located so that I can replace it. Is it under the cap?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Lacking the specific model number to look up, other Kenmore electric water heater parts diagrams show the anode rod as being at the light gray collar location (*i.e.* the plastic thing that looks the same as the red and blue pipe collars, closer to the red, but which does not have a pipe.)

There should be a hex-head nut down under there.

Be sure to turn off power and water and drain (at least some) water before attempting to remove it. Preferably turn off power before using some significant amount of hot water (usefully, not just draining it) so that the overall tank temperature is brought down.

Refill and remove air (by opening hot faucets until no more bubbles come out) before applying power after the work is complete.